# What would cause MS SQL Server to recreate an Explain Plan?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

Had a situation on a Client's MS SQL Server (2014) instance yesterday evening when a SP that was being queried by an application suddenly started timing out even though it had completed previously. My thought is that the Explain Plan for the query was somehow altered and it wasn't until I allowed the application to complete the query that a new explain plan was created.

As far as I am aware there are only two reasons an explain plan would need change:

1. The SP is recompiled
2. The database is restarted

Is there an other reason for the Explain Plan to change or is there another reason for a SP query suddenly starting to time out?

Comment: Statistics update, Proc cache being cleared, New indexes. WITH RECOMPILE hint. Just from the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks @DaveBrown, would the statistics update or Proc cache being cleared be an automatic event or user triggered?

Comment: Statistics, it depends on the version. Pre 2016 there needed to be a change of 20% of the data in a table to trigger a statistic update. In terms of cache, it depends if the engine decides it's no longer needed (rarely executed proc). These are just generic answers though, sometimes it's simply generated a Bad Plan for some reason and a recompile can sort it.

Comment: It can also on some specific parameter for which we use the Parameter Sniffing.

Comment: Thanks Guys, much appreciated